# В каком формате отобразить БД созданную через модуль SQLite3 на Python?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Не отображается БД для запросов, вот как это выглядит:

```
SQLite format 3   @     y   
                                                            y .CÃ
ø ñ ”Éš
ÇÅÌ
ÿ   ç@  ¶ñ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ‚„   tableCustomerCustomerCREATE TABLE Customer(CustomerID integer primary key, 
        LastName varchar(10) not null, FirstName varchar(10) not null,
         Adress varchar(30) not null, City varchar(15) not null, Phone bigint unique not null, 
         PetShopID int not null)/C indexsqlite_autoindex_Customer_1Customer
‚s  …9tableEmployeeEmployee
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmployeeID integer primary key,
         LastName varchar(10) not null, FirstName varchar(10) not null,
          TitleOfCourtesy varchar(5) not null, HireDate datetime not null, Adress varchar(30) not null,
           City varchar(15) not null, Phone bigint unique not null, Salary int not null, PetShopID int not null)/
C indexsqlite_autoindex_Employee_1Employee‚!!ƒutableOrderTableOrderTable    CREATE TABLE OrderTable(OrderID integer primary key, DateOfSale datetime not null,
         Discount int not null, PetShopID int not null, EmployeeID int not null, CustomerID int not null,
          PetID int, PetAccessoryID int, PetFoodID int)J‚{tablePetPetCREATE TABLE Pet(PetID integer primary key, Specie varchar(10) not null,
         Color varchar(10) not null, Gender varchar(10) not null, Age int not null, Description text not null)vƒCtablePetFoodPetFoodCREATE TABLE PetFood(PetFoodID integer primary key, Name varchar(10) not null, 
        Price int not null, PackageType varchar(10) not null, Weight varchar(10), 
        PetID int not null, ManufacturerID int not null)//ƒ-tablePetAccessoryTablePetAccessoryTableCREATE TABLE PetAccessoryTable(PetAccessoryID integer primary key,
         Name varchar(10) not null, Size varchar(10) not null, Price int not null,
          PetID int not null, ManufacturerID int not null)J%%‚WtableManufacturerManufacturerCREATE TABLE Manufacturer(ManufacturerID integer primary key, 
        Name varchar(10) not null, Adress varchar(10) not null, ProductsCategory varchar(10) not null)‚ƒ]tablePetShopPetShopCREATE TABLE PetShop(PetShopID integer not null primary key, Name varchar(10) not null,
         Adress varchar(30) unique not null, PostalCode varchar(10) not null, City varchar(15) not null,
          Phone bigint unique not null)-A indexsqlite_autoindex_PetShop_2PetShop-A indexsqlite_autoindex_PetShop_1PetShop       
   
>  Ô¨wCäµ€I!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Ø ¶%'HandyPetShopSakashwil7
 3'Customer loves petsReznychaya 52063Donetsk X³¶ Ù5     %3Pets for allPovarskoi boulevard052Odessa X¢lßÍ3 %3FavouritePetLenskiy district 21044Kyiv X¡˜Æ- )Pet Inc.Matushkina 72A063Donetsk X¡Ó»´- /CyberPetNovoapostlska 10B044Kyiv X¡<×b. 7PawKuznetskyi bridge 104052Odessa Ü¾µ02 1HappyPetNovoandriivska 11A032Zhytomyr X³³DÕ/ 3ZooBonusChervonoarmiiska 7B044Kyiv X´Õqý* )HandyZooStriletska 60A044Kyiv X¥h•t* )ChewyPetZhmachenka 22A044Kyiv X¡;:â
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: @AlTheOne Спасибо большое!

Comment: как вы добились такого "результата"?

Comment: @Jack_oS уже не суть, надо было курсач сделать, больше не актуально

Comment: @Bohdan, я через SQLiteStudio смотрю базы в sqlite, бесплатная и удобная программа. А то, что вы видите, это потому что вы открывали в текстовом редакторе файл, а сам файл бинарный (попробуйте в текстовом редакторе открыть картинки -- подобное увидите)